# the webview-based app does not launch the website

Tags: android, webview

In an attempt to start learning how web app works, I programmed a simple web app that just launches www.yahoo.com when the app starts. But the problem is that, despite the device is connected to the internet and I added the internet permission in the manifest file, the  website does not load or start when I run the app. please help to find the error or what is missing

JavaCode:

```
public class WebAppTest00 extends ActionBarActivity {

WebView webview00;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_app_test00);

    webview00 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview00);
    webview00.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview00.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.com");

    /*if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }*/
}
```

XMLCode:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.webapptest00.WebAppTest00$PlaceholderFragment" >

<WebView 
    android:id="@+id/webview00"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add http:// to your URL

It should be http://www.yahoo.com

Comment: I did but still not launching

Comment: after uninstalling and reinstalling the app, surprisingly it ran. anyway, it would not have worked without appending the prefix you suggested.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add these permissions to the manifest file and don't forget to prefix the URL with "http://";

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```